# Not able to copy a stream to a file

Tags: c#, file-io, windows-8, microsoft-metro, windows-runtime

I have to create an audio file from a stream generated by the SpeechSynthesizer.

This is the code am using

```
var stream = await _SpeechSynth.GetSpeakStreamAsync(text, this.Language);
            var reader = new Windows.Storage.Streams.DataReader(stream.GetInputStreamAt(0));
            await reader.LoadAsync((uint)stream.Size);

            byte[] bytes = new byte[stream.Size];
            reader.ReadBytes(bytes);

             var audioFile = await ApplicationData.Current.TemporaryFolder.CreateFileAsync(_AgendaAudioFilename, CreationCollisionOption.ReplaceExisting);

             using (var outputStream = await audioFile.OpenAsync(FileAccessMode.ReadWrite))
             {

                 Stream os = outputStream.GetOutputStreamAt(0).AsStreamForWrite();
                 await os.WriteAsync(bytes, 0, bytes.Length);
             }
```

I found out the problem was that at "os.WriteAsync" was not being awaited. When i put a breakpoint at that line and wait for a few secs then the file was being created properly. Shouldnt the await keyword wait till all the bytes are copied into the stream before going to the next line?

I dont mind if anyone can suggest any better way of copying an InMemoryRandomAccessStream to a file?

EDIT:

Mahantesh's answer works like a charm. Thanks a lot. But am facing a new problem.

After the file is created am trying to open it again to play it but am getting this error.

"Access is denied. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80070005 (E_ACCESSDENIED))"

This is my code.

```
if (!cacheHit)
        {
            var stream = await _SpeechSynth.GetSpeakStreamAsync(text, this.Language);

            //write the stream to disk (seems to be buggy when attempting to playback from the result of the speech synth request)
            var audioFile = await ApplicationData.Current.TemporaryFolder.CreateFileAsync(_AgendaAudioFilename, CreationCollisionOption.ReplaceExisting);

             outputStream = await audioFile.OpenAsync(FileAccessMode.ReadWrite);

             await RandomAccessStream.CopyAsync(stream, outputStream);                 

        }

        //read agenda from disk and play back the audio
        var agendaStorageFile = await ApplicationData.Current.TemporaryFolder.GetFileAsync(_AgendaAudioFilename);
        var agendaStreamFromDisk = await agendaStorageFile.OpenAsync(FileAccessMode.Read);            

        _MediaPlayer.Url = text;
        _MediaPlayer.SetBytestream(agendaStreamFromDisk);
        _MediaPlayer.Play();
```

Am getting the error at this line:

```
var agendaStreamFromDisk = await agendaStorageFile.OpenAsync(FileAccessMode.Read);
```

Any idea what might be going wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you can try with

```
await RandomAccessStream.CopyAsync(inMemoryStream, outputStream);
```

Solution to new  Problem:

```
if (!cacheHit)
    {
        var stream = await _SpeechSynth.GetSpeakStreamAsync(text, this.Language);

        //write the stream to disk (seems to be buggy when attempting to playback from the result of the speech synth request)
        var audioFile = await ApplicationData.Current.TemporaryFolder.CreateFileAsync(_AgendaAudioFilename, CreationCollisionOption.ReplaceExisting);

         using(outputStream = await audioFile.OpenAsync(FileAccessMode.ReadWrite)){
         await RandomAccessStream.CopyAsync(stream, outputStream);}

    }

    //read agenda from disk and play back the audio
    var agendaStorageFile = await ApplicationData.Current.TemporaryFolder.GetFileAsync(_AgendaAudioFilename);
   using (var agendaStreamFromDisk = await agendaStorageFile.OpenAsync(FileAccessMode.Read)){

    _MediaPlayer.Url = text;
    _MediaPlayer.SetBytestream(agendaStreamFromDisk);
    _MediaPlayer.Play();  }
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for the answer. But am facing a new problem just further down the code when am trying to open the file. I have edited the question, can you please tell me where it might be going wrong?

Comment: Needs to close output stream before opening in next time(outputStream .Close) or try "using" blocks

Answer (score 0):

As you are using `await` keyword for waiting it is better to use syncronous versions of methods, like

```
using (var outputStream = audioFile.Open(FileAccessMode.ReadWrite))
{
    Stream os = outputStream.GetOutputStreamAt(0).AsStreamForWrite();
    os.Write(bytes, 0, bytes.Length);
}
```

Comment: Even thats not working.....dunno y! But when i put a breakpoint and wait at the next line after os.Write for a few secs then outputstream gets some size. Really weird. Any idea what might be happening?